# Can the compiler coalesce atomic stores?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, atomic, compiler-optimization

The following code:

```cpp
#include <atomic>

std::atomic_bool b;

void store2() {
    b.store(true, std::memory_order::relaxed);
    b.store(true, std::memory_order::relaxed);
}
```

GCC, MSVC, and clang all emit two `mov`s like this:

```
store2():
  mov     BYTE PTR b[rip], 1
  mov     BYTE PTR b[rip], 1
  ret
b:
  .zero   1
```

*See [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cqaMbTKno)*

Would it be allowed to coalesce these atomic stores into a single `mov`? I don't believe it would violate the restrictions of `std::memory_order::relaxed` if other threads observed both atomic stores simultaneously, as if it was just one.

If it is allowed, why don't compilers perform this simple optimization?

Comment: It is allowed, but it violates rule of least surprise as well as creates implementation and performance issues. http://wg21.link/n4455

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this would be a valid transformation.  Compilers [do optimize some atomic operations](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html), but it’s [not trivial](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/Optimizations) to modify a compiler to perform such optimizations because the basic strategy for implementing them correctly consists of **disabling** optimizations that might otherwise apply to them after inlining.